# quiero obtener el valor de una celda cuando doy click en otro celda

Tags: jquery

Buen dia un saludo tengo esta tabla que tiene 3 filas y 4 columnas ..

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>columna 1</td>
<td>columna 2</td>
<td>columna 3</td>
<td>columna 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e</td>
<td>f</td>
<td>g</td>
<td>h</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

lo que quiero es que al darclick en el elemento td que tiene el valor d y h, de como resultado una alerta con el valor a y e respectivamente...

Es decir al dar click en las celdas de la columna4 me den como resultado el valor de la columna1 de esa misma fila..

gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado? Así podemos ayudarte a identificar donde esta el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más fácil que se me ocurre es utilizando clases para identificar tanto la celda sobre la que hacer click como la del dato a mostrar:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().find('.data').text());
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>columna 1</td>
    <td>columna 2</td>
    <td>columna 3</td>
    <td>columna 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td class="button">d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td class="button">h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pero si se trata de no modificar el HTML:

```js
$(function(){
  $('tr td:last-child').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().find('td:first').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>columna 1</td>
    <td>columna 2</td>
    <td>columna 3</td>
    <td>columna 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias ....saludos ...

Answer (score 0):

Basta con seleccionar primeramente los últimos `<td>` de cada `<tr>` que son los que van a tener el evento, luego dependiendo del elemento al que se le dio click seleccionamos por medio de su elemento padre al primer `<td>` que es el elemento que contiene el valor a mostrar.

Ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr td:last-child').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).parent().find('td:first-child').text();
    
    console.log(valor);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

<tr>
<td>columna 1</td>
<td>columna 2</td>
<td>columna 3</td>
<td>columna 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e</td>
<td>f</td>
<td>g</td>
<td>h</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

También podemos seleccionar el valor del `<td>` por medio de su hermano sin interactuar con el elemento padre `<tr>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr td:last-child').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).siblings('td:first-child').text();
    
    console.log(valor);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

<tr>
<td>columna 1</td>
<td>columna 2</td>
<td>columna 3</td>
<td>columna 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e</td>
<td>f</td>
<td>g</td>
<td>h</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: gracias me funciono muy bien ...saludos!!!